# Flash ActiveX in X64

Tags: c++, flash, activex, clsid

I'm trying to move my application from x86 to x64. And most of it seems to work well however, I has a Flash Player ActiveX Control in my application, and the creation of this fails in x64 builds.

```
CComBSTR flashGUID(_T("{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}"));
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString((LPOLESTR)flashGUID, &clsid); 
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) // FAILURE
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IUnknown), (void**)&m_spUnknown);
```

Any ideas what could cause this? Would I need a different clsid for 64bit?

With Flash Player 11 64 bit support was added so I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working right after asking.

I needed to download flash from [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html) and install flashplayer11_1r102_55_winax_64bit.exe in order to get it to work.